# Textstat not running functions

Tags: python, functions

I just found the link on how to install textstat on my python idle and I was successful in getting it to work.  However, when I import textstat everything seems fine until I try to run a function.  It keeps telling me that those are not defined functions.  I can go into the textstat folder on my computer, look at the code, and see that they are defined within the code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 17:11:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import textstat
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.book import
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from nltk.book import*
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
text1: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851
text2: Sense and Sensibility by Jane Austen 1811
text3: The Book of Genesis
text4: Inaugural Address Corpus
text5: Chat Corpus
text6: Monty Python and the Holy Grail
text7: Wall Street Journal
text8: Personals Corpus
text9: The Man Who Was Thursday by G . K . Chesterton 1908
>>> flesch_reading_ease(text1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    flesch_reading_ease(text1)
NameError: name 'flesch_reading_ease' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: did you try `textstat.flesch_reading_ease(text1)` ?

Comment: Yes, I just tried and it didn't like that either.  Told me the module has no attribute 'flesch_reading_ease'

Comment: Ah, now I have it semi-working.  You had to type
print textstat.flesch_reading_ease(text1)
However, now it is finding problems with every line of code within the module.  Is it probably because I am using python 2.7 and not 2.6?  If this is the case should I find a way to download 2.6 and transfer textstat to run on that?

Comment: No, python 2.7 and 2.6 are near the same, no way that this could cause a problem in each line.